# FullCalendar: bind JSON data with initialEvents after calling RestAPI call

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Running angular fullcalendar control project which is available on author site.
I am fetching events ([API ref](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)) from the server in JSON form in an array, and then would like to bind with initialEvents ([API ref](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialEvents)). How can I achieve this?

```
[
  {
    "id": 202081,
    "start": "2020-08-01",
    "isWorkDay": false,
    "budgetDailyNumber": 0,
    "modifiedBudgetDailyNumber": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 202082,
    "start": "2020-08-02",
    "isWorkDay": false,
    "budgetDailyNumber": 0,
    "modifiedBudgetDailyNumber": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: what is initialEvents?

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi, I am using its angular calendar, and there is a hook: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/angular/src/app/app.component.ts   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialEvents

Comment: Why specifically do you want to bind it to initialEvents? If it's coming from an API it probably makes more sense to link the API as an event feed directly - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed (or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function if you need more flexibility).

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
events: {
  url: 'type URL here',
  method: 'GET',
  // extraParams: {
  //   custom_param1: 'something',
  //   custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
  // },
  failure: function() {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  },
  color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
  textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}
```

Comment: @ADyson, I need to pass month and year in Get API URL parameters, so that previous and next button could work fine. How I could do so?